# How do I use document.querySelector to change css class using ngFor?

Tags: dart, ngfor, angular-dart

So I have been stuck here for some time and no matter how much research I do, I cannot find a solid answer. I may be approaching this the wrong way so feel free to tell me if I am.

I am making a web app that will display projects, like a project board. On the dashboard I am displaying the project and tasks for each project. The tasks are shown in a clickable material chip that (when finished) will, when clicked, allow you to change the task status. I would like for these chips to change color based on the severity of the status on the task, which it is pulling from a Mongo Database using jsonDecode. I also am using a Dart server to send commands to the database and receive data.

I have tried setting up a function that contains an if statement to check the task status. Then if it is found, it is supposed to change the color of the css class in the html, else, it moves on to the next status in the function. I also tried to seet all of this in the html but ngFor makes this difficult without making 5 ngIf sections, one for each task status.

dashboard_component.dart

```
Future<void> ngOnInit() async {
    await getProjects();
    await getTasks();
    doTStat();
  }


  setTStatus(taskList) {
      if (taskList.tStatus == 'Critical') {
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "purple"
          ..style.color = "black";
      } else if (taskList.tStatus =='On Hold') {
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "red"
          ..style.color = "black";
      } else if (taskList.tStatus == 'In Progress'){
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
          ..style.color = "black";
      } else if (taskList.tStatus == 'New') {
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "rgb(136, 225, 236)"
          ..style.color = "black";
      } else if (taskList.tStatus == 'Complete') {
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "lime"
          ..style.color = "black";
      } else if (taskList.tStatus == 'Canceled') {
          document.querySelector('.taskStat')
          ..style.backgroundColor = "black"
          ..style.color = "white";
    }
  }

  doTStat() {
    taskList.forEach((taskList) => setTStatus(taskList)); 
  }

  void taskDataHandle(String jsonString) {
    taskList = (jsonDecode(jsonString) as List).map((e) => new
    Tasks.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
```

dashboard_component.html

```
<material-chips class="clickable chips" *ngFor="let t of taskList">
                <material-chip
                *ngIf="t.joinID == p.id"
                [removable]="false"
                popupSource
                #source="popupSource"
                buttonDecorator
                (trigger)="showPopup(source)"
                materialTooltip="{{t.genNotes}}"
                class="taskStat"
                (click)="onTaskSelect(t)"
                [class.selected]="p  === taskSelected">
                <div>{{t.tName}}</div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px">{{t.sTech}}</div>
                <material-popup [source]="popSource" 
                                [(visible)]="showingPopup" 
                                [enforceSpaceConstraints]="false" 
                                [preferredPositions]="[position]">
                    <div header style="background: lightblue; color: black; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.8; text-align: center">
                        Select Project Status
                    </div>
                  <material-select width="2" class="bordered-list">
                      <material-select-item *ngFor="let s of statusDropdowns"
                                            (trigger)="proto = s"
                                            [selected]="proto == s">{{s}}</material-select-item>
                    </material-select>
                    </material-popup>
              </material-chip>
```

I would like for the chip colors to be changed based on the task status that they display. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use and not need `document.querySelector` at all with Angular.

Why don't use use instead

```
 ...
 class="taskStat" 
 [ngClass]="{'taskStat-Critical': t.tStatus == 'Critical', 'taskStat-OnHold': t.tStatus == 'On Hold', 'taskStat-InProgress': t.tStatus == 'In Progress', 'taskStat-New': t.tStatus == 'New', 'taskStat-Complete': t.tStatus == 'Complete', 'taskStat-Canceled': t.tStatus == 'Canceled'}"
 (click)="onTaskSelect(t)"
```

and then use CSS to assign a color depending on the applied CSS class `taskStat-Critical`, `taskStat-OnHold`, ...?

Comment: I literally realized that ngClass could be used in brackets about 2 minutes after I posted this.I stopped even trying to use it because I already had a *ngIf in my section and it wouldn't let me use *ngClass. I just finished testing and I was actually going to delete my post but ill leave it open incase someone else gets stuck here like I did. It works perfectly now though! I guess all it took was typing it all out and it triggered something. Thank you for the prompt response though!

Comment: Just putting some effort into writing a good SO question solved many problems already without the need for an answer :D Glad to hear it works for you!